# How do I prevent line numbers from appearing in content copied from ordered lists

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using a syntax highlighter, Google Prettify to be more specific, and I'm trying to select the content of the code but without the numbers of the `li` items, and when I say select I mean select with the mouse to copy and paste the code. I wonder if that's possible.

If I'm not clear, please tell me and I will try to explain it better, since English is not my 
native language.

Well.. thank guys.

Comment: Usually there is a "toggle line numbers" option - do you have a link?

Comment: here is the plugin http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/ but i think that this plugin doesnt have that option

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use JS to specify the css style `list-style` on the `<ol>` element:

```
the_list_element.style.listStyle = "none";
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: you mean dont show themm at all? The problem is that i want to show the numbers of the lines but prevent them from being copied.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think you can do that outright with the Google library. I know there are code highlighters that add a link at the top to disable line numbers for this very reason. Others just dump the source code into a textarea. One thing I've seen done is having a GIF with line numbers set as the `background-image` (obviously it runs out after a certain point). Also, I've seen the use of `<canvas>` to make this work in a more HTML5-friendly way. Hope this helps :-/

Answer (score 0):

This is a cross-browser compatibility issue, have a look [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/issues/detail?id=156):

And here for an [example](http://studiostyl.es/schemes/son-of-obsidian) that uses prettify and does not select line numbers (you need to select the code text, if you also select the line number it will copy them):

Comment: please don't put personal info in Answer Block, thanks for sharing solution.